# How to find the name of the app from activityType string in UIActivityViewController ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller, ios-app-extension

I am using UIActivityViewController to show the available app extensions for sharing my data.

I want to find out the name of the app which the user has used for sharing. For example :

activityType - **com.linkedin.LinkedIn.ShareExtension**

App Name : **LinkedIn**

Is there any way to find out the name of the app. I am using the following completion handler for UIActivityViewController

```
[activityController setCompletionWithItemsHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError) {

}];
```

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm in the same situation.

Comment: No man not yet....I have used other alternatives

Comment: Did you figure out ?

Answer (score -1):

Look this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37584455/2315538

You can check for wanted application based on activityType for example: 'net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension'