# New Line in WhatsApp vs Mail

Tags: ios, email, share, whatsapp

When sharing text from an app on IOS 9.2 you can choose from various messagin options. The problem is that most options like mail or sms expect `\n` to be the line break while WhatsApp expects `<BR>` to be the line break.

I'm told that there is no way to know in the app what the user will choose so I'm sending `\n<BR>`. While is works well for WhatsApp that ignores the `\n` it does not work well for Mail that shows the `<BR>`.

Also tried `%0A%0D` but WhatsAPP ignores.

Comment: So use the correct respective linebreak code for each application.

Comment: The problem is that there are many standards for "mail". Email can use text mode or html mode, which are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**

As of 2017-07-19, WhatsApp for iOS no longer interprets `<br>` as newline, and instead switched to `\n`.

This isn't a backwards compatible change, so if you use `<br>` you will get `Some<br>Text`. The code below should no longer be used. The good news is that you don't need to do anything: WhatsApp will handle `\n` as expected.

---

**DEPRECATED**

I used my own `UIActivityItemProvider` which, depending on the chosen activity, uses `\n` or `<br>`:

```
@interface ShareManager : UIActivityItemProvider <UIActivityItemSource>
@end

@implementation ShareManager

- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType
    id result = [self getShareText];

    if ([activityType containsIgnoringCase:@"WhatsApp"]) // You can also match against the exact id "net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension"
    {
        result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br>"];
    }

    return result;
}

@end
```

Usage:

```
UIActivityViewController *activity = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[[[ShareManager alloc] init]]];
[self presentViewController:activity animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: i set this way=>  NSString *strRemove = [textToShare stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br/>" withString:@"\n"]; but not set newline how to set new line ?

Comment: @rameshbhuja It's the other way around: the text you're going to share needs to have `<br>` instead of `\n`, so you should replace occurrences of `\n` with `<br>`: `NSString *strRemove = [textToShare stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br>"];`

Comment: My code is when i download the image with text than ...predefine text copy via generalPasteboard. than i want to apply \n line...